# Ansible: Stop a loop when the conditional is true the first time

Tags: ansible

Is there a way to stop a loop when the conditional is true the first time? In the example below, I want the value of student to be betty. But it currently will be set to brad. If I add **"and student is undefined"** to the when condition then it will work, but is there a better way? Thanks!

```
---
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
   marks:
    - name: bob
      grade: a
    - name: betty
      grade: c
    - name: jenny
      grade: d
    - name: brad
      grade: c

  tasks:
  - set_fact:
       student: '{{ item.name }}'
    loop: '{{ marks }}'
    when: item.grade == 'c'

  - debug:
      var: student
```

Comment: It's not possible. I once submitted a pull request to make it possible ([here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/55677)), but it never got any traction.

Comment: @larsks It now got at least [one positive reaction](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/55677#issuecomment-696106449) but not sure it will help... it would still be a nice feature to have

Answer (score 5):

Given the list

```yaml
  marks:
    - {grade: a, name: bob}
    - {grade: c, name: betty}
    - {grade: d, name: jenny}
    - {grade: c, name: brad}
```

---

Q: ***" ... when the conditional is true the first time ... I want the value of student to be betty."***

A: Use filters instead of a loop. There are more options:

1. Select the first item that meets the condition

```yaml
  student: "{{ marks|
               selectattr('grade', 'eq', 'c')|
               map(attribute='name')|
               first }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  student: betty
```

2. The filter *json_query* gives the same result

```yaml
  student: "{{ marks|
               json_query('[?grade==`c`].name')|
               first }}"
```

---

Example of how to find when the conditional is true for the first time in a loop

For example, let's simulate the use case of iterating a command until it succeeds. The task below iterates the list [1,2,3,4,5] and the command test the item is greater than 3. The loop will skip the rest of the list after the condition is met

```yaml
    - command: '[ "{{ item }}" -gt "3" ]'
      loop: "{{ range(1, 5 + 1)|list }}"
      register: result
      ignore_errors: true
      when: not condition
      vars:
        condition: "{{ (result|default({'rc': 1})).rc == 0 }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.results|
                 json_query('[?rc==`0`].item')|
                 first }}"
```

gives (selected relevant part)

```yaml
failed: [localhost] (item=3) => changed=true
  ...
  item: 3
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 1
  ...
changed: [localhost] => (item=4)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=5) 
...ignoring

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: '4'
```

See details in the thread [Looping a task until it succeeds](https://groups.google.com/g/ansible-project/c/OY5KSIdn0XQ/m/0vT32MfpBwAJ).