# How to make wait_for break a loop on error?

Tags: ansible

Here's my Ansible task:

```yaml
 - name: test tcp connection on servers
      wait_for:
        host: "{{ item }}"
        port: 3306
        timeout: 5
        msg: cannot connect to  "{{ item }}", aborting
      with_items:
        - server1
        - server2
        - etc ..
```

I would like to exit on first error but Ansible tests all servers:

```
TASK [test tcp connection on servers] **************************************************************************************************************************
failed: [localhost] (item=server1) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "elapsed": 3, "item": "server1", "msg": "cannot connect to  \"server1\", aborting"}
failed: [localhost] (item=server2) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "elapsed": 4, "item": "server2", "msg": "cannot connect to  \"server2\", aborting"}
```

How to make the task exiting at the first failed connection (`server1`)?

Comment: After a short research and test it seems that this is already answered generally in [Ansible: Stop a loop when the conditional is true the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63996744/6771046).