# how to end a loop by condition (Ansible)

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to check connection for an ip range for a specific port and end after one ip:port try connect successfully.

```
- name: Check connectivity
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    ip_range: "127.0.0.1/25"
    log_file: "ip_log.json"
    check_port: 25

  tasks:

    - name: Create IP List
      shell: python3 -c "import netaddr; print([str(ip) for ip in netaddr.IPNetwork('{{ ip_range }}')])"
      register: list_ip
    
    - name: Test connectivity
      wait_for:
        host: "{{ item }}"
        port: "{{ check_port }}"
        timeout: 1
        state: started
      loop: "{{ ip_list.stdout_lines[0] }}"
      register: result
      retries: 0
      until: not result.failed
    
    - name: Save a log for results
      lineinfile:
        path: "{{  log_file }}"
        line: "{{ item.item }}:{{ item.invocation.module_args.port }} - {{ item.failed }}"
      with_items: "{{ result.results }}"
```

This code works partially, because what I need is that while loop is running, when the current item connects successfully, immediately goes out from loop and continue with following steps.
How can I do that?
In the current code the `until` keyword is checking the condition after loop ends, and is not the expected result

Comment: Does gives [Ansible: Stop a loop when the conditional is true the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63996744/6771046) an idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Hi Gerard welcome to SO. Are you aware of [`|ansible.utils.nthhost`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/7/collections/ansible/utils/nthhost_filter.html#examples) instead of doing that shell-out-to-python business?

Comment: Thank you @U880D, this thread helped me to achieve what expected. Now I understand how does it work. Set on fire in my brain. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @mdaniel, I can't se how ansible.utils.nthhost can help me to iterate the valid ip's from an ip range like 100.113.141.0/25. Could you be more precise on how to achieve that using nthhost? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the community, here I post what I found to resolve it.

the keyword **until** is triggered at the end of the loop so no useful for that case.
So, I achieved the solution with the following:

```
- name: Test connectivity to ports on each IP
  #until: not results.failed
  wait_for:
    host: "{{ item }}"
    port: "{{ check_port }}"
    timeout: 1
    state: started
  with_items: "{{ ip_list.stdout_lines[0] }}"
  register: result
  ignore_errors: true
  when: not condition
  vars:
    condition: "{{ (result|default({'failed':true})).failed == false}}"
```

a condition var should must define the condition why it ends with the loop and in the keyword **when** we define the negated condition defined in vars.
When the condition is triggered, it skips the remaining items of the loop.

Also, I achieved how to get a list of IPs without using python module in the following way:

```
vars:
 network: 100.113.141.0/25

- name: Show network info
  set_fact:
    network_item: "{{ network_item|default([]) + [network | ansible.utils.nthhost(item)] }}"
  loop: "{{ query('sequence', 'start=0 end='+(network|ansible.utils.ipaddr('net')|ansible.utils.ipaddr('size')|string)) }}"
```

Thanks for the contributions to achieve the solutions.