# Is there a way to get different UUID on attempts of an until loop?

Tags: ansible

With Ansible, I need to query a MAAS API endpoint to know if a specific server is ready, and wait until it is ready.

My first idea was to use `until`:

```yaml
- name: Wait for the node 1/3
  local_action:
    module: ansible.builtin.uri
    url: "http://a.b.c.d:5240/MAAS/api/2.0/machines/{{ node_system_id }}/"
    headers:
      Authorization: "OAuth oauth_version=1.0, oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT, oauth_consumer_key={{ maas_oauth_ck }}, oauth_token={{ maas_oauth_t }}, oauth_signature=&{{ maas_oauth_s }}, oauth_nonce={{ uuid }}, oauth_timestamp={{ maas_oauth_ts }}"
    method: GET
    timeout: 120
    return_content: true
  register: result
  until: result.json.commissioning_status_name is defined and result.json.commissioning_status_name == "Passed"
  retries: 20
  delay: 15
```

Unfortunately, `oauth_nonce` is a replay protection, and cannot be the same for the same URI.

I tried to generate an UUID directly in the task, but it seems that Ansible use cache to provide always the same value:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Test
      debug:
    msg: "{{ 9999 | random | to_uuid }}"
      register: test
      until: test == true
      retries: 3
      delay: 1
```

```json
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: Test (3 retries left).Result was: {
    "attempts": 1,
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "5595e21e-9c65-5300-b549-b48d41f4a0f6",
    "retries": 4
}
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: Test (2 retries left).Result was: {
    "attempts": 2,
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "5595e21e-9c65-5300-b549-b48d41f4a0f6",
    "retries": 4
}
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: Test (1 retries left).Result was: {
    "attempts": 3,
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "5595e21e-9c65-5300-b549-b48d41f4a0f6",
    "retries": 4
}
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "5595e21e-9c65-5300-b549-b48d41f4a0f6"
}
```

I thought I could use the attempt number to generate a different UUID, but I couldn't find a variable to use:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Test
      debug:
    msg: "{{ attempt | random | to_uuid }}"
      register: test
      until: test == true
      retries: 3
      delay: 1
```

```json
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'loop_attempt' is undefined.
```

Is there a way to do what I want, whatever the method?

I know that I still have the `shell` option, I want to know if there is an Ansible way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it.
From [Retrying a task until a condition is met](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met) doc:

> When you run a task with until and register the result as a variable, the registered variable will include a key called “attempts”, which records the number of retries for the task.

So just use `test.attempt` instead of `attempt`:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Test
      debug:
        msg: "{{ test.attempt | random | to_uuid }}"
      register: test
      until: test.changed
      retries: 3
      delay: 1
```

Comment: This will probably not run but cause an error `The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'test' is undefined`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I just copy-pasted the original code to highlight the main problem. I suppose the OP put this instead of a real condition they needed. `test.changed` should work for a debug task, I fixed this.

Comment: I assume not since the error will stay. This is because `test.attempt` can't exist before the first loop run. You would need at least `"{{ test.attempt | default(0) | random | to_uuid }}"`, but that's cause other errors like `the field 'args' has an invalid value ({u'msg': u'{{ test.attempt | default(0) | random | to_uuid }}'}), and could not be converted to an dict.The error was: empty range for randrange() (0,0, 0)`

Comment: Just double checked and tested with `"{{ test.attempt | default(0) | random | to_uuid }}"` and as expected they UUID does not change.

Answer (score 0):

> ***It seems that Ansible use cache to provide always the same value***

That is the expected behavior for your given example.

The `to_uuid` happens only once on the first iteration. This caused by the way variables becomes registered and handled internally. For the `retries` loop run the variable content for `until` condition will stay at the initial value since it is set (registered) at "compile time" and not "re-set during run time".

The following example will show the behavior.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    RETRIES: [1, 2, 3]

  tasks:

  - name: Set Facts in loop
    set_fact:
      RESULT: "{{ ansible_loop.index }}"
    # Inner loop
    until: RESULT == '3'
    retries: 3
    delay: 1
    # Outer loop
    loop: "{{ RETRIES }}"
    loop_control:
      extended: true
      label: "{{ item }}"
```

As one can see from the result output, the `retries` behaves like an loop for the inner object, which is a single outer loop state here.

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: Set Facts in loop (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Set Facts in loop (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Set Facts in loop (1 retries left).

TASK [Set Facts in loop] *****************************
failed: [localhost] (item=1) => changed=false
  ansible_facts:
    RESULT: '1'
...
  ansible_loop_var: item
  attempts: 3
  item: 1
FAILED - RETRYING: Set Facts in loop (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Set Facts in loop (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Set Facts in loop (1 retries left).
failed: [localhost] (item=2) => changed=false
  ansible_facts:
    RESULT: '2'
...
  ansible_loop_var: item
  attempts: 3
  item: 2
ok: [localhost] => (item=3)
```

To summarize, the construct can't work in that way unless the initial condition is already `true`. This is shown in the example run #3.

---

> ***Is there a way to do what I want, whatever the method?***

Probably. A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Create result set
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    register: result
    when: item | int < 4                 # until
    loop: "{{ range(1, 20, 1) | list }}" # retries
    loop_control:
      extended: true
      label: "{{ item }}"
      pause: 1                           # delay
```

creates a similar behavior resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Create result set] *****
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) =>
  msg: 1
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) =>
  msg: 2
ok: [localhost] => (item=3) =>
  msg: 3
```

One will need to introduce an additional [stop loop when the conditional is true the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63996744/6771046).